# install_keras() in RStudio, tensorflow 2.4.0 requires gast==0.3.3, but you have gast 0.4.0 which is incompatible

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to work with the keras library in RStudio to use the keras_model_sequential() function but can't overcome the following error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.4.0 requires gast==0.3.3, but you have gast 0.4.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.4.0 requires grpcio~=1.32.0, but you have grpcio 1.38.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.4.0 requires h5py~=2.10.0, but you have h5py 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
```

When I install the version that is proposed in the error message in the terminal, I'm getting the same error the other way around:

```
(env) (base) ➜  env pip install gast==0.3.3
```

```
Collecting gast==0.3.3
  Using cached gast-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Installing collected packages: gast
  Attempting uninstall: gast
    Found existing installation: gast 0.4.0
    Uninstalling gast-0.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled gast-0.4.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.5.0 requires gast==0.4.0, but you have gast 0.3.3 which is incompatible.
```

Does anyone have experience with this? Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this has been resolved in more recent versions of keras/tensorflow. In most cases, this should work:

```
install.packages("keras")
reticulate::install_miniconda()
keras::install_keras()
```

In cases where you are trying to use reuse a previous python environment that has some conflicting dependencies (likely the cause of your observed error message), you can temporarily workaround most of them by passing `pip_ignore_installed = TRUE`:

```
keras::install_keras(pip_ignore_installed = TRUE)
```